# How to add new database row to Custom Parse class using Android

Tags: java, android, database, parse-platform

I uploaded a CSV file to import my database to Parse under a Custom class in Parse.

But for some reason, I can't make a new row via code on Android using the Parse APK.

For example, lets say the my custom class is called "newClass". I have many columns under this class and no new rows can be added. Here is the code I have so far:

```
//class was populated via CSV file
ParseObject database = new ParseObject("newClass");

database.put(firstColumn, val1);
database.put(secondColumn, val2);
database.put(thirdColumn, val3);
database.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        Toast.makeText(coolActivity.this, "Item added to database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

When I check parse.com to see if the item was added, I don't see anything updated and it is the same database as before.

Comment: are you getting any error in this code?

Comment: @ved no errors at all

Comment: let me check the parse exception

Comment: I'm so stupid... "invalid type for key x, expected number, but got string"